# Any alternatives to Google Streetview?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-maps

I am seeking to find out if we have alternatives to Google maps' streetview?  There is nothing wrong with Google streetview.

Comment: why ?  what is wrong with Google Street View. Please add *body* to your question instead of copying the title.

Comment: see http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-some-sites-or-lets-make-a-list-of-x-type-questions/76#76 Even with your edits this is just a poll of webapps. Consider adding requirements to your question or move it to CW.

Comment: This "question" is anything but a list directory and not a real question.

Comment: Alternative: Walking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bing Maps**: http://www.bing.com/maps/

**Map Jack**: http://mapjack.com/ is another (as recommended by joyjit below).

See example:
http://www.bing.com/maps/explore/?FORM=MLOMAP&PUBL=GOOGLE&crea=userid1743go6a1c1270db6e7f374a897e012428c985e#5003/s=w/5872/lat=32.797172&lon=-117.243132&alt=-17.24&z=30&h=70.1&p=2.9&pid=5082

They also do arial view from planes, so better definition.

Comment: Note: They don't have nearly the coverage that Google does.

Comment: *Your computer isn’t supported
Bing maps doesn’t work on your computer
You can use Bing Maps on computers running Windows XP and later or Intel-based Mac OS X 10.4.8 and later.*

Answer (score 2):

There is a street view from Yandex for cities like Kiev or Moscow: http://maps.yandex.ru/-/CJc.6xd

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is [**MapJack**](http://mapjack.com).

- Pro: pictures are of higher
  resolution
- Con: Very poor (geographical) coverage, compared to Google Street View

From their "[About](http://mapjack.com/About.html)" page:

> Jack may look like an ordinary guy,
>   but he sure gets around, with the help
>   of us of course -- a small team
>   dedicated to high quality Immersive
>   Street-Side Imagery, and bringing mass
>   coverage online.
>
> Mapjack.com showcases
>   a new level of mapping technology.
>   What others have done with NASA
>   budgets and Star Wars-like equipment,
>   we've done on a shoestring budget,
>   along with a few trips to Radio Shack.
>   Specifically, we developed an array of
>   proprietary electronics, hardware and
>   software tools that enable us to
>   capture an entire city’s streets with
>   relative ease and excellent image
>   quality. We have a complete low-cost
>   scalable system encompassing the
>   entire work-flow process needed for
>   Immersive Street-Side Imagery, from
>   picture gathering to post-processing
>   to assembling on a Website.

Answer (score 1):

Google have spent a lot of time and money on Streetview already. In the UK they've reached 96% coverage ([source](http://www.overseaspropertymall.com/regions/european-property/uk-property/google-street-view-now-has-full-uk-coverage/)). And that's just one country. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Street_View) has a more global perspective.

The problem everyone else has is that they'd be playing catch-up, so unless they've got the resources like Microsoft or perhaps Apple, they couldn't afford it. Even if someone else started the first choice is still going to be Google.

It's one of those cases where being first effectively gives you a monopoly. The other providers need to find a different unique selling point (USP). In Bing's case it looks like it's aerial imagery from planes. The other alternative is to go for countries/cities where Google doesn't offer Streetview at the moment. The problem here is - will these locations generate enough traffic to pay for the service?

Answer (score 1):

For Eastern and Central Europe: [NORC](http://www.norc.eu/street-view/).

Answer (score 1):

For the UK Yell.com have just released a new map system;

http://www.yell.com/maps/MapAction.do

with streetcam for some major cities and a nice 3D implementation;

http://www.yell.com/maps/MapAction.do?mapSearchType=locSearch&location=buckingham+palace+london&scrambleSeed=39375287&scrambleSeed=14045093&lat=51.50107361239192&lon=-0.14178360066401402&zoomFactor=2&type=&viewerMode=3dmap&pitch=39&heading=270&height3d=500

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these websites should do other TYPES of street view like interior view like shopping malls/stores?

Trail view for hiking and camping?  Water View for boating?  Park view for parks and recreation spots?

Anybody else have any ideas?